# remove leading 0 in exponential format in python

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I have the following code in Python 3.1

```
"{0:.6E}".format(9.0387681E-8)
```

Which gives a string of `9.038768E-08`, but I want the string `9.038768E-8`  with the leading 0 of `E-08` removed.  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
"{0:.6E}".format(9.0387681E-8).replace("E-0", "E-")
```

or better as JBernardo suggests

```
format(9.0387681E-8, '.6E').replace("E-0", "E-")
```

You need to do a replace for `E+0` as well if you have big numbers

Comment: For single objects, it's better to use the `format` function: `format(9.0387681E-8, '.6E')`

Comment: @gnibbler: I retract my comment; I think your answer is safe. (+1)

Comment: @unutbu, putting it in a function and testing the corner cases would be a good idea regardless.