# Format number to scientific notation, but to 3e-5 instead of 3e-05

Tags: python, format, scientific-notation

I have very small or very big number which I want print in scientific notation:

```
pattern = "{:.0e}"
value1 = pattern.format(0.00003)
value2 = pattern.format(0.00000000005)
value3 = pattern.format(999999999) 
print(value1, value2, value3)
# Current output: 3e-05 5e-11 1e+09
# Desired output: 3e-5 5e-11 1e+9
```

Is there any better way to format number into form without `0` after `-` than `value1.replace("-0", "-").replace("+0", "+")`? I would like the number to be as short as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove leading 0 in exponential format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863143/remove-leading-0-in-exponential-format-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use decimal.

```
import decimal
pattern = "{:.0e}"
value1 = pattern.format(decimal.Decimal('0.00003'))
value2 = pattern.format(decimal.Decimal('0.00000000005'))
value3 = pattern.format(decimal.Decimal('999999999'))
print(value1, value2, value3)
```